# Just solution check- Taylor serie around $x_0=2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I have this solution (I hope it's ok to post picture instead writing in Latex), and I just need someone to check if this is ok precedure for finding serie around point $x_0=2$?

-
[image]

Comment: It looks very correct to me. Good job ! Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is correct (doing this just to close question from more answers and views)